# Django post initialization modules

Tags: python, django

Is there a way that I can call some functions/modules right after all the settings in Django have been imported?

Comment: Please state **specifically** what you're trying to accomplish.  Often, it's already part of Django.  Sometimes it goes in `urls.py`.  Sometimes it's better as middleware.

Answer (score 2):

Probably, the best place for this is the end of the `settings.py` ;-)